# Knocked Over PC, Stopped Working

Tags: desktop-computer

so my PC is always on the floor. I accidentally knocked it down and it hit the floor=, which is carpeted by the way.
It stopped working. It gets to the Windows 10 loading screen, then freezes. Did something break inside it, or did something just get loose? I need to get it working quickly bc some stuff is on there ***I NEED***. Was the HDD damaged?

Comment: From what you've told us, it is impossible to say anything... There are far too many things that could have happened. We'll need more information. Are you confident with taking electronics apart? Have you had a look inside?

Comment: Nope! Going to wait for my Dad to come home in about an hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SSD, almost unlike but if you have a HDD with a spinning platter its possible.

I would check easy stuff first, you may have knocked something loose.

Power your PC off, unplug the power from power supply and open your case. Then take the ram out and reinserting them, if you have any expansion cards installed like video card, raid card, USB expansion etc... do the same. If your motherboard gives you post codes that can may help.

If that doesn't help reboot the PC and spam F8 like a mad-man and see if you can boot into safe mode ( I would try Safe Mode with network or even try "last known good configuration"

If you can get to safe mode or "last known..." let us know

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when my Dad gets home. I don't want to damage it even more! I am already going to be in deep waters.